# Increase the Scope of Passed Arguments

Tags: c#, scope

I have a handful of variables passed from one form to another, but now I'm realizing these variables can't be accessed outside the form method.

```
 public Form3(int str, int dex, int vit, int arc, int hp, int mp, int sp, string name, string charClass)
    {
        ...
    }
```

I'd like to be able to access the arguments from other methods. Is it possible to increase the scope of these arguments within the class itself, or do I need to go to the roots and declare them differently?

Comment: Are you familiar with [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx)? This is generally how you make information available (even read-only) to other classes.

Comment: You can expose a method or property from your Form using the public access modifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make them class-level members.  For example:

```
public class Form3
{
    private int Str { get; set; }

    public Form3(int str)
    {
        Str = str;
    }

    private void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        // here you can access Str
    }

    // other methods, etc.
}
```

Comment: Ah, I have a lot to learn with the get; set; function. Thanks! I appreciate your help.

Comment: @user5930165: Technically you don't need to make it a property like this, it could just be a class-level variable.  But if you plan on making any of them publicly accessible from other objects then a property would be better practice in that case.  There's no reason not to use private properties, so it's generally a good habit to keep.